# Flash Builder can't find PPAPI flash debugger

Tags: google-chrome, flash-builder

I was able to get flash builder to work with the NPAPI version of the debugger, but I have installed chrome 64-bit (v 38.0.2125.101), which seems to only work with the PPAPI version found [here](http://labs.adobe.com/downloads/flashplayer.html). With that version installed I am back to this error message:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\plugins\NPSWF32.dll

Flash Builder cannot locate the required version of Adobe Flash Player. You might need to install the Flash Player or reinstall Flash Builder.

Do you want to try to run your application with the current version?
```

That directory doesn't exist, and it doesn't look like it ever did, so I have no idea why Flash Builder is looking there, or how to tell it to look elsewhere.